# how to assign my profile user to be a User instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i have 2 applications in django project "accounts" for managing user and authetications and the "BP" for managing the BusinessPlan
every application have her own models, urls, and views

this is accounts/models.py :

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

this is accounts/views.py

```
def signup(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registration_form.is_valid():
            user = registration_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            user_id=user.id
            return redirect(reverse('bp:profile',kwargs={'user_id':user_id}))
    
    return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})
```

this is bp/models.py :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #.....other fields....
```

ther is other fields like name, birthdate, phone, ....

this is bp/views.py:

```
def profile(request,user_id):

    if request.method =='POST':
        user=User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        form = NewProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile=form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=user
            profile.save()
    else:
        form=NewProfileForm()
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'form':form})
```

i create the user and it's done then i try to add the profile after validating every data it send me this message:

[image]

how to fix it

Comment: I assume the OneToOne relation of Profile -> User is not right. I think you have used the wrong User model class here.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions that i think can help you:
1)Check if you added your user model in settings: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.User'`
2)Make sure implemented right User Model in your Profile models.py: `from your_app.models import User`
3)Add print to every your step and check where`s the problem

Comment: i update my models but it still the same problem

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: same things also when i test if profile has an attribut called user with : if hasattr(profile, 'user'): it send me false

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass user instence not id, need to correct like this

```
def profile(request,user_id):

    if request.method =='POST':
        user=User.objects.get(user__id=user_id) # need correct this
        form = NewProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile=form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=user
            profile.save()
    else:
        form=NewProfileForm()
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'form':form})
```

## you can also pass current user instance like this

```
def profile(request):

    if request.method =='POST':
        user=User.objects.get(user=request.user) 
        form = NewProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile=form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=user
            profile.save()
    else:
        form=NewProfileForm()
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'form':form})
```